# How do I get Dynamic form Value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to create dynamic form that will allow user to select option and populate price automatically in input field but unfortunately it only work in first field, it does not work in another added field. please help.

Here is my code

```
<select class="form-control item" name="madic" id="medicine" required>
              <option value="" selected >Select Madicine</option>
              <?php 
    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM pharmacy WHERE Qty != '0'";
    $result2 = $con->query($query2);
    if($result2->num_rows> 0){
       while($optionData1=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
        $mid =$optionData1['p_id'];
        $madicine =$optionData1['madicine'];
        $mrate =$optionData1['mrate_price'];?>
       
    ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $mid ?>" data-price=<?php echo $mrate; ?>><?php echo $madicine; ?></option>
         <?php }} ?>
            </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-2">
              <input type="text" name="mrate[]" value="0"  class="mrate form-control " id="mrate"  readonly>
            </div>
            
             <div class="col col-md-1">
              <input type="text" name="Qty[]" class="form-control Qty" value="1" id="Qty" >
              
            </div>
             <div class="col col-md-1">
              <input type="text" name="mdiscount[]" class="form-control mdiscount" value="0" id="mdiscount" >
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-2">
              <input type="text" name="pack[]" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: Tab,box .." >
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-1">
             <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
            </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('select[name="madic"]').change(mediSum);
function mediSum(){
  var elemente = $('select[name="madic"]').find('option:selected');
  var desc1 =  Number(elemente.data("price")); 
   var rate2 = $('.mrate').val(desc1);
  
}

Here I have Appended
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = i;
     $('#add').click(function(){
      i++;

      $('#mad').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="col col-md-4"><select class="form-control medicine" name="madic[]" id="medicine" required><option value="" selected >Select Madicine</option><?php 
    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM pharmacy WHERE Qty != '0'";
    $result2 = $con->query($query2);
    if($result2->num_rows> 0){
       while($optionData1=$result2->fetch_assoc()){
        $mid =$optionData1['p_id'];
        $madicine =$optionData1['madicine'];
        $mrate =$optionData1['mrate_price'];?>
           ?><option value="<?php echo $mid ?>" data-price=<?php echo $mrate; ?>"><?php echo $madicine; ?></option><?php }} ?>
            </select></div><div class="col col-md-2"><input type="text" name="mrate[]" value="0"  class="mrate form-control " id="mrate"  readonly></div><div class="col col-md-1"><input type="number" name="Qty[]" class="form-control Qty" value="1" id="Qty" ></div><div class="col col-md-1"> <input type="number" name="mdiscount[]" class="form-control discount" value="0" id="mdiscount" ></div><div class="col col-md-2"><input type="text" name="pack[]" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: Tab,box .." ></div><div class="col col-md-1"><button type="button" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger remove_row">-</button></div></div>');
     });

    $(document).on('click','.remove_row', function(){
      var row_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#row'+row_id+'').remove();
     });
  });



$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = i;
     $('#add').click(function(){
      i++;

      $('#mad').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="col col-md-4"><select class="form-control medicine" name="madic[]" id="medicine" required><option value="" selected >Select Madicine</option><option value="1" data-price="125">Amoxline1</option><option value="2" data-price="163">Amoxline2</option><option value="3" data-price="723">Amoxline3</option>
</select></div><div class="col col-md-2"><input type="text" name="mrate[]" value="0"  class="mrate form-control " id="mrate"  readonly></div><div class="col col-md-1"><input type="number" name="Qty[]" class="form-control Qty" value="1" id="Qty" ></div><div class="col col-md-1"> <input type="number" name="mdiscount[]" class="form-control discount" value="0" id="mdiscount" ></div><div class="col col-md-2"><input type="text" name="pack[]" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: Tab,box .." ></div><div class="col col-md-1"><button type="button" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger remove_row">-</button></div></div>');
     });

    $(document).on('click','.remove_row', function(){
      var row_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#row'+row_id+'').remove();
     });
  });
  
  $('select[name="madic"]').change(mediSum);
function mediSum(){

 
  var elemente = $('select[name="madic"]').find('option:selected');
  var desc1 =  Number(elemente.data("price")); 
   var rate2 = $('.mrate').val(desc1);
  
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <!--- madicine row ----->
          <div class="row col col-md-12 madi" id="mad" style="display: block;">
            <br>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
              <select class="form-control item" name="madic" id="medicine" required>
              <option value="" selected >Select Madicine</option>
             
           <option value="1" data-price="125">Amoxline1</option>
            <option value="2" data-price="163">Amoxline2</option>
             <option value="3" data-price="723">Amoxline3</option>
         <?php }} ?>
            </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-2">
              <input type="text" name="mrate[]" value="0"  class="mrate form-control " id="mrate"  readonly>
            </div>
            
             <div class="col col-md-1">
              <input type="text" name="Qty[]" class="form-control Qty" value="1" id="Qty" >
              
            </div>
             <div class="col col-md-1">
              <input type="text" name="mdiscount[]" class="form-control mdiscount" value="0" id="mdiscount" >
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-2">
              <input type="text" name="pack[]" class="form-control" placeholder="eg: Tab,box .." >
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-1">
             <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- end medicines -->
```

Example of what I  want when user select then data-price value display in next input field even when I add another row.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this really a problem related to PHP or AJAX? While there is PHP code, you haven't shared any AJAX code

Comment: it is jquery issue, I am newbie in jquery

Comment: Better if you load all selections first then use ajax to process details on submit. then on success, refresh the div/inputs/selection containing the details

Answer (score 0):

When you called

```
$('select[name="madic"]').change(mediSum);
```

you have specified that all `select` tags existent (at the time) in the document, having the `name` of `madic` should handle `change` events by calling `mediSum`. However, when such a `select` is created later, it does not have this handler. So, I recommend changing your code to:

```
$('select[name="madic"]:not(.initialized)').change(mediSum).addClass('initialized');
```

So, any `select` tags having the `name` of `madic` that were not initialized (we know that by the fact that they don't have the `initialized` `class` yet) will be associated with the given `change` handler and will receive the `initialized` `class`. Now, you have a feature that dynamically adds similar `select` tags. Those new tags will not have the `initialized` class, so running the same code when the add event happens as the one suggested above should solve your issue.

Comment: I have added it but not solved.

Comment: @ELITEINTERNATIONALLTD can you edit your question, add a snippet to it so I could reproduce your problem easily?